# Salesforce Community Email Customization

Tags: community, email, customization

I am trying to customize the email that is being sent when a new user self registers on the community.
I am using System.UserManagement.initSelfRegistration method to send a verification code to the email address used by the new user. I do not find a way to customize this email. The contents of the email below. This is not the one time password email, which I can change on the Workspace. This is an email sent when the user tries to create a new account on the community.

Hello,

You recently attempted to register a new Community account.

Browser: Chrome
Operating System: Windows 10

To confirm your account, let's verify your identity. Enter the following code where prompted.

Verification Code: 68621

Comment: Isn't this the same as the community's Welcome Email template?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, it seems this template is not yet possible to configure: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000U4vDQAS